# How to upgrade the version of a transitive dependency in SBT?

Tags: scala, build, sbt

In my SBT configuration, is there a way that I can force a dependency to upgrade to the latest version of a transitive dependency?
e.g. I have

```
"org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-neo4j" % "4.0.0.RELEASE"
```

as a dependency which I have declared in a plugin and use across many projects. It internally uses

```
"org.neo4j" % "neo4j-ogm" % "1.1.2"
```

as a transitive dependency.

I want to upgrade to

```
"org.neo4j" % "neo4j-ogm" % "1.1.4"
```

Is there a way to achieve this without switching to manual mode of doing all dependency management?

Answer (score 2):

If you add the transitive dependency as an explicit dependency with the newer version, then SBT / Ivy will resolve the conflict between the two by choosing the newer version:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-neo4j" % "4.0.0.RELEASE",
  "org.neo4j" % "neo4j-ogm" % "1.1.4"
)
```

After running `sbt compile`, you can look at the Ivy dependency report in `target/resolution-cache/reports/<my-project>-compile.xml` (open it in a web browser) for a full summary of which dependencies were chosen by Ivy and how all conflicts were resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the version `"org.neo4j" % "neo4j-ogm" % "1.1.4"` in libraryDependencies. The version specified will override (evict).

```
  +-org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:4.0.0.RELEASE
     +-org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm:1.1.2 (evicted by: 1.1.4)
     +-org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm:1.1.4
     | +-ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3
     | | +-ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.3
     | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
```